# LoadPosition via Jquery - Joomla 3.x

Tags: jquery, joomla

My aim is to load a `<script>...</script>` into the beginning of each article within Joomla 3.x.
To do this I've created a custom html module with the code. I'm then calling this using loadposition via jQuery. Like so,

```
<script>
   jQuery("#startOfPage" ).after("<p>{loadposition content_lock}</p>");
</script>
```

I'm seeing the text for the loadposition being added i.e the tag but it doesnt translate it into the code (i.e that is added to the `content_lock` position).

Is there any easier way to achieve this. i.e add code to the beginning of each article? Or a way to get the above working?

Comment: I am unclear on what you are trying to achieve.  I am also unsure of what problem you are having.  But in general I think you would be better off to loadposition the module first and then move the element with jQuery.  Your currently approach will have problems escaping the content that is passed by the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sury why you need to use jquery for this? Why not just add

```
<p><jdoc:include type="modules" name="content_lock" style="none" /></p>
```

to display your module?

---

**But if you need to load it with jquery...**

The javascript is executed after the browser has loaded the page, so the module cannot be loaded like you did it. If you need to load this with javascript, you have to use an ajax call to display the module content. Something like this, i suppose:

in your templates/yourtemplate - folder add a file content_lock.php containing:

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="content_lock" style="none" />`

Add position content_lock to templates/yourtemplate/templateDetails.xml

```
<positions>
  ...
  <position>content_lock</position>
  ...
</positions>`
```

Load the module with ajax:

```
<script>jQuery.get('index.php', {tmpl: "content_lock"}).done(
  function(data){
    jQuery("#startOfPage" ).after(data);
  }
);
</script>
```

Display your module content in position content_lock. You can test that content_lock.php works as expected by accessing

*yoursite/index.php?tmpl=content_lock*